# Python API JSON dictionary loop

Tags: python, json, list, data-structures

My code is working, but I know there has to be a more efficient way to accomplish it and better exception handling.

**API data format per item:**

```
{  
   u'logEnd':False,
   u'logBegin':True,
   u'links':{  
      u'self': u'https://192.168.15.140/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/policy/accesspolicies/00505689-7E52-0ed3-0000-184683643989/accessrules/00505689-7E52-0ed3-0000-000268439552'
   },
   'sourceNetworks':'any-src',
   u'name':u'Peer-to-Peer Blocking',
   'sourceZones':'any-src-zn',
   u'enabled':True,
   'sourcePorts':'any-src-port',
   u'logFiles':False,
   u'vlanTags':{ },
   u'applications':{  
      u'applications':[  
         {  
            u'type':u'Application',
            u'id':u'61',
            u'name':u'BitTorrent'
         },
         {  
            u'type':u'Application',
            u'id':u'571',
            u'name':u'BitTorrent tracker'
         },
         {  
            u'type':u'Application',
            u'id':u'1214',
            u'name':u'ExtraTorrent'
         }
      ]
   },
   u'sendEventsToFMC':True,
   u'action':u'BLOCK',
   'destinationPorts':'any-dest-port',
   'destinationNetworks':'any-dest',
   u'variableSet':{  
      u'type':u'VariableSet',
      u'name':u'Default Set',
      u'id':u'76fa83ea-c972-11e2-8be8-8e45bb1343c0'
   },
   u'type':u'AccessRule',
   u'id':u'00505689-7E52-0ed3-0000-000268439552',
   'destinationZones':'any-dst-zn',
   u'metadata':{  
      u'category':u'--Undefined--',
      u'accessPolicy':{  
         u'type':u'AccessPolicy',
         u'name':u'PVmain1-ACPolicy-201610251131',
         u'id':u'00505689-7E52-0ed3-0000-184683643989'
      },
      u'section':u'Mandatory',
      u'domain':{  
         u'type':u'Domain',
         u'name':u'Global',
         u'id':u'e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f'
      },
      u'timestamp':1482339574186
   }
}
```

**Working Python Script**

```
for i in results:
    response = requests.request("GET", i, headers=headers, verify=False)
    raw=response.json()
    raw.setdefault('name', "noname_rule")
    raw.setdefault('action', "no_action")
    raw.setdefault('sourceNetworks', "any-src")
    raw.setdefault('destinationNetworks', "any-dest")
    raw.setdefault('sourcePorts', "any-src-port")
    raw.setdefault('destinationPorts', "any-dest-port")
    raw.setdefault('sourceZones', "any-src-zn")
    raw.setdefault('destinationZones', "any-dst-zn")
    interesting_keys = ('name', 'action','sourceZones', 'sourceNetworks', 'sourcePorts', 'destinationZones', 'destinationNetworks', 'destinationPorts' )
    subdict = {x: raw.get(x, "any") for x in interesting_keys if x in raw}

    if 'objects' in subdict['sourceZones']:
        srczn = subdict['sourceZones']['objects'][0]['name']
    elif 'literals' in subdict['sourceZones']:
        srczn = subdict['sourceZones']['literals'][0]['port']
    else :
        srczn = subdict['sourceZones']

    if 'objects' in subdict['sourceNetworks']:
        srcnet = subdict['sourceNetworks']['objects'][0]['name']
    elif 'literals' in subdict['sourceNetworks']:
        srcnet = subdict['sourceNetworks']['literals'][0]['value']
    else :
        srcnet = subdict['sourceNetworks']

    if 'objects' in subdict['sourcePorts']:
        srcprt = subdict['sourcePorts']['objects'][0]['name']
    elif 'literals' in subdict['sourcePorts']:
        srcprt = subdict['sourcePorts']['literals'][0]['port']
    else :
        srcprt = subdict['sourcePorts']

    if 'objects' in subdict['destinationZones']:
        dstzn = subdict['destinationZones']['objects'][0]['name']
    elif 'literals' in subdict['destinationZones']:
        dstzn = subdict['destinationZones']['literals'][0]['port']
    else :
        dstzn = subdict['destinationZones']

    if 'objects' in subdict['destinationNetworks']:
        dstnet = subdict['destinationNetworks']['objects'][0]['name']
    elif 'literals' in subdict['destinationNetworks']:
        dstnet = subdict['destinationNetworks']['literals'][0]['value']
    else :
        dstnet = subdict['destinationNetworks']

    if 'objects' in subdict['destinationPorts']:
        dstprt = subdict['destinationPorts']['objects'][0]['name']
    elif 'literals' in subdict['destinationPorts']:
        try:
            dstprt = subdict['destinationPorts']['literals'][0]['port']
        except KeyError:
            dstprt = "0"
    else :
        dstprt = subdict['destinationPorts']

    #print >> target, "%d,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" %(number, subdict['name'],subdict['action'],srczn,srcnet,srcprt,dstzn,dstnet,dstprt)
    #print "%d,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" %(number, subdict['name'],subdict['action'],srczn,srcnet,srcprt,dstzn,dstnet,dstprt)
    number+=1
    time.sleep(.5)
    print raw
```

Can you suggest other ways that would improve error handling, performance, readability, etc?

Comment: `srczn = subdict['sourceZones'].get('objects', [{'name': None}])[0].get('name')` would give you the value None if 'objects' or 'name' don't exist.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you see repeated code, perhaps it could be collapsed into one function that can reused over and over?  Refactoring the code this way probably doesn't make it faster, but it does make it easier to read and understand.

```
def getSubdictData(subdict, fieldname, prop2):
    if 'objects' in subdict[fieldname]:
        return subdict[fieldname]['objects'][0]['name']
    elif 'literals' in subdict[fieldname]:
        if prop2 in subdict[fieldname]['literals'][0]
            return subdict[fieldname]['literals'][0][prop2]
        else:
            return "0"
    else :
        return subdict[fieldname]

for i in results:

    ...

    srczn = getSubdictData(subdict, 'sourceZones', 'port')
    srcnet = getSubdictData(subdict, 'sourceNetworks', 'value')
    srcprt = getSubdictData(subdict, 'sourcePorts', 'port')
    dstzn = getSubdictData(subdict, 'destinationZones', 'port')
    dstnet = getSubdictData(subdict, 'destinationNetworks', 'value')
    dstnet = getSubdictData(subdict, 'destinationPorts', 'port')

    ...
```

Also note that I removed the try-catch you were using to detect if a field existed or not.  If the object/code provides a way for you to determine that this field existed or not, we should use that instead of relying on a sloppy try catch to perform our logical operations.  Try catches used like this are hard to read and perform badly.  In this case it wouldn't matter, but its good practice not to abuse try catches like this.